# shell script to replace a word in a given sentence

Tags: shell, unix

I Need a unix shell script that when executed accepts a sentence and replaces a given word with another word.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a command to do this, try sed.

For example, to replace `hello` with `goodbye` in the sentence `hello world`:

```
$ sed 's/hello/goodbye/g' <<< "hello world"
goodbye world
```

If you want this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]
then
     echo "Usage: $(basename $0) word replacement sentence" >&2
     exit 1
fi

word="$1"
replacement="$2"
sentence="$3"

echo "${3//$1/$2}"
```

Example:

```
$ replace.sh hello goodbye "hello world"
goodbye world
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sed:

sed 's/source/destination/' file_with_sentence.txt

- source is the searched word
- destiantion is the replacement
- file_with_sentence... is sef explained

You can wrapp it into some unix shell script (you did not tell which shell are you using)

or even better:

echo "This is my sentence" | sed 's/source/destination/'